# Expected Method Body Error in XCODE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

In a application I have declared a Category `

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface UIImage (StackBlur) // Expected method body
- (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)inradius ;
-(UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)firstImage eggShape:(UIImage*)secondImage rect:(CGRect)rect;
-(UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage*)firstImage ;
@end
```

`it shows error at commented line. Please help. here is implementation code`

```
#import "UIImage+StackBlur.h"


@implementation  UIImage (StackBlur)




- (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)inradius 
{


    return finalImage;
}
-(UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)firstImage eggShape:(UIImage*)secondImage rect:(CGRect)rect {
   return theImage;
}
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image {

    return theImage;
}
@end
```

`

Comment: Expected Method body, Expected selector for Objective C Method

Comment: i know this is far fetched but did u checked whether your interface and implementation lines are same..

Answer (score 3):

`UIImage` is part of `UIKit`, so `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` rather than `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (StackBlur)
- (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)inradius ;
-(UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)firstImage eggShape:(UIImage*)secondImage rect:(CGRect)rect;
-(UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage*)firstImage ;
@end
```

Comment: @Sandroid Then the issue is in the source file that `#import`s this file; please post it.

Comment: I have posted implementation part.

Comment: @Sandroid I don't see anything wrong there.  Please post everything related to the compilation error from the Xcode log pane.

Comment: Every time I run build failed and in Issue navigator it shoes parse error in this file.

Comment: @Sandroid There is a log pane which shows the compiler options and error message directly from the compiler; please post that here.